# Intellij and generated sources, imports always inline

Tags: intellij-idea, import

I'm having this frustrating experience where Intellij is acting as if I have 'Use fully qualified class names' is checked, but only for classes that are my generated sources. In other words instead of putting the import at the top of the class, it simply uses the fully qualified class name in-line.

I've added my generated-sources directory as a source directory but the problem remains.  I'm wondering if I need to mark a sub directory as the 'source directory' but nothing I try seems to work.

[image]

Comment: marking as "generated sources" usually works. are generated sources present in the same module or there's some dependency to it?